# How to select text from pop up bar

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm desperate how to get the text of an information message that only appears for a few seconds. The text is

[image]

Code for appear is:

```
<simple-snack-bar class="mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted">
<span>Osoba byla v ROB nalezena.</span><!---->
```

and this is the selenium code for check the text:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//simple-snack-bar[@class ='mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted']").get_attribute("text")
```

But I always get none as an answer. I don't know how to get it anymore. Whether it works at all.

Comment: `simple-snack-bar` is not a standard HTML tag. Selenium has to work extra hard to find these - like string matching. It is quite possible that it takes longer to find this tag, than the the element is visible.

Comment: Try something like `.find_element_by_class("mat-simple-snackbar")`? Note: I do not use Python - I assume this is py. You should add the correct language tag to your question.

Comment: yes, it is Python.